# How to generate transaction number with special requirements using php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first ever question on StackOverFlow and I hope someone can help me find a solution for this using PHP.
    I would like to generate a transaction number for each transaction the user is making as follows:

```
Transaction number:    JM-170100001
JM= User ID
17= Year
01= Month
00001= transaction number
```

Regards

Comment: Does your `transaction number` a primary key in DB? How are you creating two letter combination User ID?

Comment: Thank you Thamilan for the quick response,
Well yes it is a primary key and regarding the users i don`t have much thats why i choosed to make it only two letters. otherwise if its not possible i can make it 3 letters instead.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this following snippet:

```
$userID = "James";

// Insert into table which returns last_insert_id

// $transactionNo = last_insert_id; (say 1)

$uniqueValue = strtoupper(substr($userID, 0, 3)).date("-ym").sprintf("%05d",$transactionNo);

// Update table with $uniqueValue where transaction_num = last_insert_id
```

So `$uniqueValue` holds the desired value. `JAM-170100001`

---

**Explanation**

- [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) - Converts string to upper
- [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) - Returns a
  part of string
- [date](http://php.net/date) - prints the current date/time in the
  provided format
- [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) - formats a string - here you need
  transaction number in 5 characters with 0 padding

Comment: Thank you
I`ll try that and let you know.